# CSVhelper writeLine, null pointer halfway during a for-loop

Tags: java, csv, for-loop, nullpointerexception, string-length

For a java simulation project I have a log file that keeps track of everything that happens during a single run. I do this by adding objects of a custom TimeLog.class to a List. When the simulation is complete I loop through this list and write an ArrayList of strings for each entry, followed by writing it to a csv file using the following "CSVHelper" class which I found online (credits to Keke Chen).

Creating ArrayList of strings:

```
public static void saveData(List<TimeLog> data, String fileName, Simulator simulator, 
        ArrayList<String> header) throws Exception {
    File csvFile = new File(simulator.getOutputFolder()+fileName);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(csvFile);
    Writer fw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
    CSVHelper.writeLine(fw, header);
    for (TimeLog entry : data) {
        ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
        row.add(String.valueOf(entry.getTime())); //time of entry, double
        row.add(String.valueOf(entry.getMessageType())); //type of message (SETUP, DEBUG, EVENT, ERROR)
        if (entry.getEvent() == null) {
            row.add("");
        } else { 
            row.add(entry.getEvent().getTypeName()); //event type if event
        }
        row.add(entry.getLog()); //message
        CSVHelper.writeLine(fw, row);
    }
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
}
```

CSVHelper.writeLine :

```
/** Class for processing csv file.
* created by Keke Chen (keke.chen@wright.edu)
* For Cloud Computing Labs
* Feb. 2014
*/
public static void writeLine(Writer w, ArrayList<String> values) throws Exception  {
    boolean firstVal = true;
    for (String val : values)  {
        if (!firstVal) {
            w.write(",");
        }
        w.write("\"");
        for (int i=0; i<val.length(); i++) {
            char ch = val.charAt(i);
            if (ch=='\"') {
                w.write("\"");  //extra quote
            }
            w.write(ch);
        }
        w.write("\"");
        firstVal = false;
    }
    w.write("\n");
}
```

For debugging purposes, I catch exceptions thrown by the simulator, add information about them to my logging list, write the log file, and then throw the exception again. This way, when a problem occurs I can look in the log file what happened.

Until recently this worked just fine, but now I get a NullPointerException during the 2nd for-loop in the writing process. For some reason the line

```
for (int i=0; i<val.length(); i++)
```

throws an exception halfway during a string. If I open the log file that is created, the last entry has a half finished message or timestamp as well (for example: "tool X was res" instead of "tool X was reserved for item Y" or "212" instead of "212312.16").

Is there any limitation to writing csv files, keeping lists in java, using for-loops on characters of strings, or anything else that I am not aware of? This is giving me quiet the headache.

Ciao,
Robin

EDIT: As requested, an example of the list entries:

```
//initiating:
private List<TimeLog> logging = new ArrayList<>();

//message:
public void message(MessageType mt, String s, Event e) {
    if (saveLog) {
        logFile.add(new TimeLog(now(), mt, s, e)); //now() gets the current time of the simulator
    }
}

//example:
Event e = new ReservationEvent(simulator.now(), X, Y);
simulator.message(MessageType.EVENT, "Tool "+X.getId()+" was reserved for item "+Y+getId(), e);
```

this is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at model.simulator.transport.input.CSVHelper.writeLine(CSVHelper.java:27)
at model.simulator.TimeLog.saveData(TimeLog.java:73)
at model.simulator.Simulator.endSimulation(Simulator.java:98)
at model.simulator.Simulator.runSimulation(Simulator.java:64)
at test.simulator.compare.TestFullFab.testRunning(TestFullFab.java:147)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
```

Something else that I noticed due to Emax's comment. I added

```
System.out.println("0:"+row.get(0)+", 1:"+row.get(1)+", 2:"+row.get(2)+", 3:"+row.get(3));
```

in the saveData method, just before CSVHelper.writeLine(fw,row), to see the list of strings before they get written. This resulted in the full list of logs in the console, so also the ones that did not (or partly) get written to the csv-file. Somehow, the TimeLog for-loop continues while the writeLine is throwing exceptions.

EDIT2: structure of TimeLog:

```
public class TimeLog {
    private double time;
    private MessageType mt;
    private String log;
    private Event e;

    public TimeLog(double time, MessageType mt, String log, Event e) {
        this.time = time;
        this.mt = mt;
        this.log = log;
        this.e = e;
    }

    //see full method above
    public static void saveData(List<TimeLog> data, String fileName, Simulator simulator, 
        ArrayList<String> header) throws Exception { ...

    //further more, there are some getters
}
```

An example of the output in the console as a result of the System.out.println() line:

```
0:27131.490112666303, 1:EVENT, 2:TOOLEVENT, 3:Tool input event, item 3998 has gone into tool QSD301
```

keep in mind that the 0:,1:,2:, and 3: are not in the original list but added in the println() method.

UPDATE: Using Emax's idea of printing the values where it returns null revealed the problem. The value of val indeed becomes null, and it happens at the NullPointerException (which has no message), so e.getMessage() returns null. Strangly enough, the Writer simply does not write all the values in the csv file, but seems to have some kind of delay (maybe it first collects a default number of characters before actually writing it to the file or something?). Because of this, I thought the NullPointer happened during a loop through val, while it had already finished. Thanks for the help!

Comment: the StackTrace of the exception is the first source of information to check! at least to get the correct line where the Exception is being thrown.

Comment: @MRRommers post the structure of the TimeLog class and also an example of the instances that you are passing as list to the saveData method

Comment: @MRRommers Maybe i figured out! The stacktrace is pointing at TimeLog.java on line 73, check if the (ArrayList<String> header) contains a null!!!!

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, the header does not contain a null, this line is also written to the csv file correctly and the writeLine method gets way further than the first line. TimeLog line 73 is the one containing: CSVHelper.writeLine(fw, row);

Comment: BTW, why don't you make your `TimeLog` fields `final`? Also, how many threads are involved? Any chance the list is modified by many threads while being populated?

Comment: @MRommers look at the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible reason that cause a NullPointerException on that line is that val is null since val is taken from a list, the problem bubble up to:

```
    row.add(String.valueOf(entry.getTime()));
    row.add(String.valueOf(entry.getMessageType()));
    row.add(entry.getEvent().getTypeName());
    row.add(entry.getLog());
```

One of this add is adding a null to the list, you should check for one of this.
**However post the full stracktrace including (if present) the "Caused By"**

## UPDATE

Try to modify writeLine like this:

```
        [...]
        if (!firstVal) {
            w.write(",");
        }
        w.write("\"");

        // EDIT HERE
        if (val == null) {
            System.out.println("This val is null: " + values);
        }
        // .....

        for (int i = 0; i < val.length(); i++) {
        [...]
```

Post the output with the case that caused the NullPointerException

Comment: That's what I figured, but the created file contains string values in the final cell as well. Just now, the last cell contains the start of a message, but stops halfway. The variable val is not changed during the for loop and contains writable characters, but the loop just stops.

Comment: @MRommers Hi, Can you post the straktrace and an example of the List<TimeLog> data that you are passing to the method